# Error create table in azure storage explorer

Tags: azure-storage

[i am getting error
"Type error:Cannot read property 'statuscode' null at process response call back"
 while creating table in microsoft azure storage explorer when using external storage,while locally table is creating perfectly.please help.][1]

Comment: Could you please supply more info about this issue such as, screenshot of error, the version of the storage explorer? We can get the latest version of storage explorer from the [link](http://storageexplorer.com/releasenotes.html). How to connect to the azure storage, connection string or   account with password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while creating table in Microsoft azure storage explorer when using external storage, while locally table is creating perfectly.

Please have a try to check whether the network is smooth. The error message indicates that can’t get the response status from the azure storage. It seems that something wrong with the network. If the network is smooth, please try to create the storage table again. If the issue is still repro, please have a try to troubleshoot with following ways:

- Try to download the latest version of [Microsoft azure storage](http://storageexplorer.com/releasenotes.html) tools
- Create another storage account and try it again
- Please have a try to use another computer to check it.

Comment: yes that was a network problem ,i was using proxy server.Thanks very much.